# R settings in VSCode keep reseting after VSCode monthly update

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

Everytime VSCode updates I face an issue with VSCode and R. Everytime the VSCode updates my R instance automatically opens with:

```
> C:/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
Error: unexpected '/' in "C:/"
> conda activate base
Error: unexpected symbol in "conda activate"
```

I have Python installed with Anaconda, so these 2 lines make sense when I open Python. However, by doing it with R, it crashes all my R scripts.

Every month I make some changes into the settings.json to make it stop. However I never remember where to do it and every month I go by trial and error until it stops doing that. My question is: is there a long term fix for this?

My current settings.json is the following and I have not fixed it yet this month:

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "One Dark Pro",
"jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
"github.copilot.enable": {
"quarto": false,
"\*": true,
"yaml": false,
"plaintext": false,
"markdown": true,
"python": true
},
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,
"\[python\]": {

        "editor.formatOnType": true,
    },
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.0\\bin\\R.exe",
    "r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.0\\bin\\R.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
    "[r]": {
    
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
    },
    "r.plot.useHttpgd": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "r.lsp.diagnostics": false,
    "editor.rulers": [80,120]

}
```